# Dynamic binding in angular2 in image src tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular, image

I have below line of code in my html, but it is not working

```
src="assets/images/{{"id"}}.png"
```

where `id` is coming form my ts component.
Can i have a better way or working line to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried binding via

```
<img [src]="'assets/images/'+id+'.png'" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont need "" inside the interpolaton, try

You can do it like :

```
[src]='"assets/images/"+id+".png"'
```

OR

```
src='assets/images/{{id}}.png'
```